# Understanding a paragraph on pg.134 in AT.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The paragraph is given below:

> [image]

**My question is:**

Why is $H_{n}(S^n)$ considered as infinite cyclic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $H_n(S^n)\cong\mathbb{Z}$, which is the infinite cyclic group.

Comment: And why $H_{n}(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Using singular homology it can be proved by induction. The proof is on page 114 of Hatcher.

Comment: what about using cellular homology?

Comment: I have looked at pg.114 and I did not find it ..... maybe we have different edition? what is on pg. 114 is the reduced homology and not the relative homology

Comment: Could you show me the proof please? or give me a link that explains the proof?

Comment: $\tilde{H_n}(S^n)=H_n(S^n)$ - just from the definition of reduced homology.

Comment: For a proof using cellular homology, consider the CW complex on $S^n$ with one $0$-cell and one $n$-cell. Then the cellular chain groups are all zero apart from $C_0$ and $C_n$ which are both $\mathbb{Z}$, and the boundary maps are all zero, so the cellular homology groups are the same as the cellular chain groups.

Comment: I can not see how $\tilde{H}_{n}(S^{n}) = H_{n}(S^{n})$ just from the definition ..... could you explain this please?

Comment: The only thing that changes in reduced homology is the extra map $\varepsilon:C_0\to \mathbb{Z}$; all the other boundary maps are the same. So for any space $X$, $\tilde{H_n}(X)=H_n(X)$ for $n>0$. The only thing that is different is the zeroth reduced homology group - this is related by $H_0(X)\cong \tilde{H_0}(X)\oplus\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Is this only because of the definition of reduced homology?

Comment: Yes, reduced homology groups are defined to be the homology goups of the augmented chain complex with the extra map $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank u so much for your patience and thorough explanation :)